# get the final result after looping through a list of data

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a set of data in an array. Where the first value will denote the number of records and second number will denote the number of data in one record accordingly. Data will loop and calculate until the number of records equals to 0.

> 3 -> set 1 - no of records 3
>   2 -> record 1 contain two data values
>   10.00 -> data1
>   20.00 -> data2
>   4 -> record 2 contain four data values
>   15.00
>   15.01
>   3.00
>   3.01
>   3
>   5.00
>   9.00
>   4.00
>   2 -> set 2 - no of records 2
>   2
>   8.00
>   6.00
>   2
>   9.20
>   6.75
>   0

I need to calculate the sum of one set of records and need to divide it from the no of records and then need to minimise that value from each of the record to get the value (which gets after reduction of summation/no of records)

output

> (1st set of records)
>   1.99
>   8.01
>   10.01
>   (2nd set of records)
>   0.98 -> ((8.00+6.00) + (9.20+6.75))/2 - (8.00+6.00)
>   0.98

This is the code I came up with but the results I am getting are different and could not find where it got wrong.

my output

> 171.38 <- 1st set of records
>   135.36
>   117.36 
>   118.57 <- 2nd set of records
>   102.62

```
// (inputLines is the name of the array with data)

int data = 0;
float temp = 0;
List<string> tempOutputFileList = new List<string>();

while (inputLines[data] != "0")
{
    var listOfPeople = new List<float>();
    int people = int.Parse(inputLines[data]);

    for (int n = 0; n < people; n++)
    {
        data = data + 1;
        int receipts = int.Parse(inputLines[data]);

        for (int p = 0; p < receipts; p++)
        {
            data = data + 1;
            temp += float.Parse(inputLines[data]);
            listOfPeople.Add(temp);

            if (listOfPeople[n].ToString() != null)
            {
                listOfPeople[n] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    float sum = 0;
    string tempValue = null;
    double receiptValue = 0;

    foreach (float item in listOfPeople)
    {
        sum += item;
    }

    for (int v = 0; v < people; v++)
    {
        receiptValue = (sum / people - listOfPeople[v]);
    }

    data++;
    tempOutputFileList.Add(" ");
    listOfPeople.Clear();
}

foreach (string val in tempOutputFileList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

Comment: can you post the array declaration with the data?

Comment: @Darkonekt Actually I got the dat from a text file and store those in a String array. Below is the code I used. 

 public static String[] inputFileLines = null;

try
            {
                inputFileLines = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
            }


            foreach (string val in inputFileLines)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }

My output

3

2

10.00

20.00
4
15.00
15.01
3.00
3.01
3
5.00
9.00
4.00
2
2
8.00
6.00
2
9.20
6.75
0
$171.38
$135.36
$117.36
 
$118.57
$102.62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compute average after summing a whole set of records. However, on the other hand you can also simplify the way to compute the average if you only store the sums per people. See the following code that produces the results you expected (however some with different sign):

```
        int data = 0;
        List<string> tempOutputFileList = new List<string>();

        while (inputLines[data] != "0")
        {
            var listOfPeople = new List<float>();
            int people = int.Parse(inputLines[data++]);

            for (int n = 0; n < people; n++)
            {
                int receipts = int.Parse(inputLines[data++]);
                float tempPeople = 0;

                for (int p = 0; p < receipts; p++)
                {
                    tempPeople += float.Parse(inputLines[data++]);
                }

                listOfPeople.Add(tempPeople);
            }

            foreach (float item in listOfPeople)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(listOfPeople.Average() - item);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```